# php/mysql If ternary

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help me with my query format. my output is:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET Notes = 'testyyy',
       0 
 WHERE Id = '1'
```

...when it should be:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET Notes = 'testyyy , 
       Notify = '0' 
 WHERE Id = '1'
```

PHP:

```
if(!isset($_POST['main'])) {
$up = "UPDATE TABLE SET Notes = '".$_POST["field"]."' ",";
$up .= " Notify = '".($data["Notes"] == '') ? '0' : '1'."'";
$up .= " WHERE Id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
echo $up;
mysql_query ($up);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the ) to the other side of '1':

```
$up .= " Notify = '".($data["Notes"] == '' ? '0' : '1')."'";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$up = "UPDATE TABLE SET Notes = '".$_POST["field"]."' ",";
```

doesn't look right

```
$up = "UPDATE TABLE SET Notes = '".$_POST["field"]."' ,";
```

and ensure that your $_POST values are escaped

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$up .= " Notify = '".($data["Notes"] == '' ? '0' : '1')."'";
```

or you can also split it into two as:

```
$up .= " Notify = '";
$up .= ($data["Notes"] == '') ? '0' : '1'."'";
```

Also `TABLE` is a MySQL reserved word, you need to place it in back ticks.